# How to use a function defined in a bash profile in a bash script?

Tags: bash, function, export, profile

I have a Projection function in my bash_profile. Now I am trying to call this function from a bash script however I get a not found error. How do I make the projection function visible to the bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must export the function

```sh
export -f foo
```

[`ref`](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/master/.functions)

Comment: where does the export statement go?

Answer (score 0):

The sane but not necessarily elegant approach is to put the function in a separate file, and source it from your profile and from your script.

You need to export the function if you want to make it available to all your scripts, but -- as with global variables -- this is not very maintainable in the long run.